# Calculus limits with sin and cos

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(2x)-2x\cos(2x)}{2x-\sin(2x)} $$

I know the answer is 2 I just don't know how to do the work for it.

Comment: Do you know L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Yes! I thought that was how you do it but once I did it one time it came out to be 1/0 so i'm not sure if I did it wrong or what

Comment: do it more than once

Comment: But can't you only do it if its in the form 0/0 or inf/inf??

Comment: so bring it into that form and again do it

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use L'H rule for once and then use trigonometric identities to get into proper form.

I'm here assuming that you're well aware about trigonometric identities and using L'H rule.

Some identities that you need to look out for (this question):

$${1 - \cos 2x = 2\sin^2 x \\ \sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x}$$

After applying L'H rule on numerator and denominator, you get: 
$$\begin{align} &\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{2\cos (2x) - 2\cos (2x) + 4x\sin 2x }{2 -2\cos 2x} \\
=&\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{4x\sin 2x}{2(1 - \cos 2x)} \\
=&\lim_{x \to 0} \cfrac{4x \sin 2x}{4\sin^2 x} \\
=&\lim_{x \to 0} \cfrac{ 2x \sin x \cos x}{\sin^2 x} \\
=&\lim_{x \to 0} \cfrac{2x \cos x}{\sin x} \\
=&\lim_{x \to 0} \cfrac{2\cos x}{\cfrac{\sin x}{x} } \end{align}$$

Use, $\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ .

And you'll get : $\lim_{x\to 0} 2\cos x = 2$

Answer (score 2):

we will use the facts $$\sin(small) = small - \frac 16 small^3 + \cdots, cos(small) = 1 - \frac12 small^2 + \cdots $$ now we have  $$\frac{\sin(x) - x\cos(x)}{x-\sin (x)} = \frac{x-\frac13x^3 + \cdots -x(1-\frac12x^2 + \cdots)}{x-(x-\frac13x^3+\cdots)}=\frac{\frac16x^3+\cdots}{\frac 13x^3 + \cdots} \to 2 \text{ as } x\to 0.$$

but $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x) - 2x\cos(2x)}{2x-\sin (2x)} =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x) - x\cos(x)}{x-\sin (x)} = 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I will use the usual limits
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{2},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^{3}}=-\frac{1}{6}.
$$
First we re-write the original expression as
$$
\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}=\frac{\sin x-x+x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}=\frac{%
\frac{\left( \sin x-x\right) +\left( x-x\cos x\right) }{x^{3}}}{\frac{x-\sin
x}{x^{3}}}=\frac{\frac{\left( \sin x-x\right) }{x^{3}}+\frac{\left( 1-\cos
x\right) }{x^{2}}}{\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}}
$$
Passing to the limit as $x$ tends to $0$ one gets
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x-\sin x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}%
\frac{\frac{\left( \sin x-x\right) }{x^{3}}+\frac{\left( 1-\cos x\right) }{%
x^{2}}}{\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}}=\frac{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{%
\left( \sin x-x\right) }{x^{3}}+\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left(
1-\cos x\right) }{x^{2}}}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}}=\frac{%
-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{6}}=2.
$$